# How do I create a variable that grabs specific image url on html page and outputs it to pinterest as pinned image using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, url-routing, pinterest

I am trying to utilize Pinterest's pin it button on my website. The directions on the Pinterest 'create a button' section are straight forward except for the fact that I'm only given the option of entering the url of the image I want pinned. This can be very strenuous and redundant, especially for someone working on a website that has more than a hundred pages (pages containing product images). So I figured I'd use some Javascript (jQuery preferably) to do the trick.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="pinterest"></div>
<!--Sample Image-->
<div id="pic">
    <img id="sampleimage4div" src="images/wonderfulpicture.jpg" />
</div>


<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com....
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/... etc
```

jQuery Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentURL = $(location).attr('href');
    var description = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('title'));
    var imageURL = encodeURIComponent($('#sampleimage4div').attr('src')+currentURL);

$('#pinterest').append('<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+currentURL+'&media='+imageURL+'&description='+description+'"class="pin-it-button"count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png"title="Pin It"/></a>');        
}); 
</script>
```

I was able to alter/customize the page 'URL' and 'description' but for some reason I'm failing to get the image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentURL = $(location).attr('href');
var imageURL = encodeURIComponent($('#sampleimage4div').attr('src')+currentURL);
```

Those lines of code are the problem. use

```
var currentURL = $(location).attr('host')
var imageURL = encodeURIComponent("//" + currentURL + $('#sampleimage4div').attr('src'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If you can, may you explain briefly why the line was a problem as well as your solution so that I may learn from this error? Also, I tried your approach but still not working, I added the link to this site http://shankombo.com/bluestem/socMed-2.html. Maybe this can help?

Comment: Basically I switched around the URL, so the `http://your.domain.com/` came before the `image/image-name.jpg`

Comment: Edited my answer above.
I've added the `"//"` at the start of the `imageURL` so the browser will choose `http:` or `https:` depending on what the user is using.

Comment: I see what you mean, I made the changes as suggested. However, I this is what got "//http//shankombo.com/bluestem/socMed-2.htmlimages/suitfornexttime.jpg". Getting close, all thats needed is to have "/" between 'socMed-2.html' and 'images/suitfornexttime.jpg' like so "http//shankombo.com/bluestem/socMed-2.html/images/suitfornexttime.jpg". I played around with the code, but no luck. Whats the best way to do that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're still using this line: `var currentURL = $(location).attr('href');` change the `'href'` for `'host'`, and add another `/`. Like this: `var imageURL = encodeURIComponent("//" + currentURL + "/" + $('#sampleimage4div').attr('src'));`

Comment: Hey ahren, thanks a lot for your help! I got your code to work and even better, I learnt from it;)

Answer (score 0):

once use this:

```
$('#pinterest').append('<a href="anything"><img src='+imgvariable+'></a>');
```

also you can use here:

```
$('#sampleimage4div').attr('src')+currentURL //at the place of this
```

use

```
$('#sampleimage4div').attr('src','src_which_you_want')
```